# Azure Kinect DK, Body tracking: Mapping separate avatars on separate skeletons

Tags: c#, azure, unity-game-engine, azurekinect

To recreate my issue, I've setup a project in Unity3d 2020, using [this](https://github.com/microsoft/Azure-Kinect-Samples/tree/master/body-tracking-samples/sample_unity_bodytracking) sample project.
Here I can successfully map an avatar to a single skeleton. In my project, however, I want to map multiple skeletons - not only the closest, as the sample provides.

This far I've successfully rendered multiple skeletons, but when I try to map separate avatars on each of them - the two avatars will follow the motion of only one of the skeletons in the scene.

The following code is used to setup the avatars:

```
var avatarPrefab = Instantiate(avatarPrefab, new Vector3(0,0,0), Quaterion.identity);
avatarPrefab.GetComponent<PuppetAvatar>().KinectDevice = this;
avatarPrefab.GetComponent<PuppetAvatar>().CharacterRootTransform = avatarPrefab.transform;
avatarPrefab.GetComponent<PuppetAvatar>().RootPosition = this.transform.GetChild(i).transform.GetChild(0).gameObject; // gets the pelvis of each "rootBody" prefab.
```

The creator of the PuppetAvatar.cs script has yet to release any updates to support multibody tracking, but I posed a similar [question](https://github.com/microsoft/Azure-Kinect-Samples/pull/52#issuecomment-1111879545) in [this](https://github.com/microsoft/Azure-Kinect-Samples/pull/52) thread.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at MoveBox: https://github.com/microsoft/MoveBox-for-Microsoft-Rocketbox

> Movebox can parser the SMPL body models extracted by an external tool for 3D multi-person human pose estimation from RGB videos.

And it supports Azure Kinect DK

Comment: Initially this seemed like the solution. However after reading their GitHub documentation and [research paper](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/uploads/prod/2020/10/MoveBox-Democratizing-MoCap-for-the-Microsoft-Rocketbox-Avatar-Library.pdf) I found the following: "The current system was tested recording one person ...  but we hope to extend the system for multi actors, or maybe multiple actors online which can help multiuser production ... ". It seems these changes have yet to be made and/or published.